# Question about build output from Rider on Mac

Tags: .net, rider, avaloniaui

lately I was looking for solution for C# dev on Mac and I found this great tool which is Rider. But I've big problem. I'm coding Avalonia project which will be used only on Windows stations. When I'm publishing my app .exe is generated and everything would be cool but when I open this app on Windows first thing I can see is that stupid Console Host window from .Net. I know that this issue corresponds to the .Net Runtime but maybe someone here has managed to bypass this window?

I use .net6 win-x64 during publish.

Comment: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions

Comment: Avalonia is not the case , the problem seems to be with .net so I posted question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the solution for my problem. It seems that when you install Rider on Windows which in this case works under Parallels it compiles app as expected in opposite to Visual Studio. I forgot to add that my computer is M1 Pro which is ARM and VS currently doesn’t have ARM support. So in summary if you want to build apps on Mac M1 for Windows platform use Rider on Parallels Windows.